# R geo: from points to SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, spatial, geo

I am trying to create a `SpatialPolygonDataFrame` starting from a data.frame with points, but I am not sure about the methodologies. I succeeded in obtaining a list of spatial polygons, but failed to convert them in a `SpatialPolygonsDataframe`.

Here my data structure:

```
               coordinates parcours_id   tm_cid         date_mesure tm_type tm_mnc tm_dbm
34268 (2.670962, 48.48172)             24680199 2017-07-04 01:38:36     lte      1   -113
34269 (2.670522, 48.48981)             24680199 2017-07-04 01:38:44     lte      1   -117
34270 (2.668994, 48.49398)             24657926 2017-07-04 01:38:59     lte      1   -116
34271 (2.668994, 48.49398)             24657926 2017-07-04 01:39:05     lte      1   -116
34272 (2.668069, 48.49653)             24657926 2017-07-04 01:39:17     lte      1   -116
34273  (2.667893, 48.5005)             24657926 2017-07-04 01:39:29     lte      1   -108
```

I want to create polygons by tm_cid. I have tried to follow `?SpatialPolygons`

```
    polygons=c()
    for (value in unique(mesures.sp$tm_cid)){
      sub=subset(mesures.sp,mesures.sp$tm_cid==value)
      x=Polygon(sub@coords)
      polygons=c(polygons,x)
    }

    polygons=as.list(polygons)
#polygons my srl (list with Polygon Class Objects)
    ID=unique(mesures.sp$tm_cid)
    all_poly=c()
    for(value in 1:length(polygons)){
    poly=Polygons(polygons[value], ID[value])
    all_poly=c(all_poly,poly)}

    all_poly=as.list(all_poly)  
#all_poly is my sr (list of object of class SpatialPolygons-class, shouldn't be a list but I failed to do otherwise)


    spatPoly=c()
    for(value in 1:length(polygons)){
      spol=SpatialPolygons(all_poly[value])
      spatPoly=c(spatPoly,spol)}

    ID=as.data.frame(ID)
    spdf=c()
    for(value in 1:length(polygons)){
      data=ID[value,1]
      df=SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(spatPoly[[value]],data=data)
      spdf=c(spdf,df)
    }
```

I am getting this error:

> Error in if (length(Sr@polygons) != nrow(data)) stop(paste("Object
>   length mismatch:\n    ",  :    argument is of length zero

Any idea?

Comment: Add your answer as a separate answer instead of editing your post! In this way you'll be helping others with the same issues.

Comment: I don't think it's nice to suppress the answer before I have edited. My computer crashed, I came here because I lost what I have done, and I have to redo. I understand your point, but please next time don't suppress the answer BEFORE the comment is added. The way you do it, it can finish that nobody get the answer.

Comment: All the revisions are saved, you can check them out here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44947371/revisions

Comment: Yes I found it. But I really think next time it's better to ask to the person to add an answer and to edit. The more important thing is to keep the answer visible. By the way, it will also save you time (I would have done the edit myself).

Answer (score 0):

```
require(rgeos)
require(rgdal)
require(maptools)
```

(mesure.sp is a `SpatialPontDataFrame`)

```
   polygons=c()
    for (value in unique(mesures.sp$tm_cid)){
      sub=subset(mesures.sp,mesures.sp$tm_cid==value)
      x=Polygon(sub@coords)
      polygons=c(polygons,x)
    }

    polygons=as.list(polygons)
#polygons my srl (list with Polygon Class Objects)
    ID=unique(mesures.sp$tm_cid)
    all_poly=c()
    for(value in 1:length(polygons)){
    poly=Polygons(polygons[value], ID[value])
    all_poly=c(all_poly,poly)}

    all_poly=as.list(all_poly)  
#all_poly is my sr (list of object of class SpatialPolygons-class, shouldn't be a list but I failed to do otherwise)


    spatPoly=c()
    for(value in 1:length(polygons)){
      spol=SpatialPolygons(all_poly[value])
      spol@proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
      spatPoly=c(spatPoly,spol)}

    spoly=spatPoly[[1]]
for(value in 2:length(spatPoly)){
  spoly=c(spoly,spatPoly[[value]])
}

    spoly=as.list(spoly)
spdf=c()
    for(value in 1:length(polygons)){
        data=as.data.frame(ID[value])
  row.names(data)=data$ID

      df=SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(spatPoly[[value]],data=data)
      spdf=c(spdf,df)
    }

    final_spdf=spdf[[1]]
for(value in 2:length(spdf)){
  final_spdf=spRbind(final_spdf,spdf[[value]])}
```